# Can I get TeX / LuaTex / XeLatex to output positions of text?

Tags: rendering

I oversee printing of a daily newspaper for a small number of readers.

For a variety of reasons I want to be able to take an image snapshot of a given article as typeset. This image goes into a photo processing workflow, so it can't just be the text of an article, it has to be the post-laid out, styles and fonts applied actual pixels.

I know that a TeX rendering engine knows exactly where everything goes on page, but I don't know how to request and get this metadata out -- are there any gurus here who could help?

I guess ideally I'd get a top left and bottom right of a box output somehow, then I can do the rest rendering the pdf and virtually snapshotting it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use (\pdf)savepos to save positions. See e.g. the zref-savepos package.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. To summarize, \zsavepos{headlinestart}This is the headline\zsavepos{headlineend} would get me two zrefs, is that right? And then I would use \typeout{\zposx{headlinestart}}, etc to get them logged?